# Allow Angular $sanitize to keep certain tags

Tags: angularjs, ngsanitize

I want to enable the user in my app to use certain white-listed HTML tags (like `<div></div>` & `<span></span>`) but disable other HTML tags like `<script></script>`, `<input/>`.

I can create a custom directive in order to just do it manually, but I understood there's a way to do this using `$sanitize`, `$compileProvider` and the `$compileProvider.directive`. I can't find any documentations on this feature.

How to disable all html besides `<div>` tags without any attributes, using `$compileProvider.directive` instead of my own directive?

Comment: you can't define specific tags to trust; both `$sce` and `$sanitize` provide ways to trust URLs, but the tags appear to be hard coded.  see the code starting at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js#L213/

Comment: Thanks for this comment! What I did is created my own sanitizer (based on the angular one) and used that.

It's mostly the same, but with a few global functions that allow me to configure the sanitizer in an `angular.module('XX').config(...)` sort of fashion in order to add or remove things from the whitelist and blacklist of tags and attributes.